# how can you use pam-dbus without using gnome

Tags: dbus

I have been playing around with pam-dbus on a old slow box that is too slow for gnome/kde so I have been using ratpoision as the window manager. I was able to configure it to show a notification on the desktop whenever an authentication attempt was made, but I can't figure out how to approve/disapprove the attempt.

Comment: Someone is actually using pam-dbus? I am considering removing it from Debian... if you still use it, let me know!

Comment: I haven't got working yet.

Comment: Ok, had to read some of my own code again. Are you running the pam-dbus-notify tool that comes with pam-dbus?

Comment: http://www.galago-project.org/specs/notification/index.php is the homepage listed in aptitude.

Answer (score 0):

pam-dbus uses a feature where a notification contains not only text, but can also allows for Yes-No-interaction. Not all providers of notifications support that feature, if yours does not then you cannot use pam-dbus.

You can check that your notification daemon supports action using this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pynotify
pynotify.init("pam-dbus-test")
n = pynotify.Notification("Title","Text")
n.add_action("action", "An action", lambda _: False)
n.show()
```

Comment: notification-daemon 0.7.6-1

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ben/testnote.py", line 6, in <module>
    n.show()
glib.GError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Notifications was not provided by any .service files

Comment: @hildred: Ok, I am surprised that you get any notification at all then. Are you sure that notification-daemon is running (not just installed)? After all, you say that you are *not* using GNOME. And what exactly does the notification that you see say?

Comment: Your code works on Debian/Gnome3 libnotify version 0.1.1-3.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner what??